# Having Trouble executing javascript in VScode debugger

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

device: Macbook Pro 2016
OS: MacOS 10.13.5
editor software: Visual Studio Code

I installed VScode a few days ago and have been trying to run a simple hello world program in the debugger that is part of VScode. I initially had the issue that node was not installed but after I installed it I then got the error "Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)."

I've tried a few other things such as: installing "node exec" and "code runner".

Also this is what my Launch.Json looks like

```
    {
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": 
[

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "name": "Launch program",
        "port": 9229
    },

]
```

}

Comment: try this configration, change your server.js to your main file.

`{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js"
}`

Comment: @UbaidAzad, sorry if this question is really dumb but what do you mean by change my server.js to my main file? like replace the words "server.js" with my file name "app.js"? Also thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: yes exactly. you have replace it with your main app.js file.

Comment: do I have to change this everytime I want to run a different project?

Comment: for every project you have, you have different launch.json and it depends on your project structure.